# How do I connect a printer to the Ubuntu Guest on Oracle VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.04, virtualbox

How do I connect a printer to the Ubuntu Guest ?

When running as a bridged network I can find the networked printer only.  The printer attached to the host PC is invisible to the guest.

There are 2 printers.  One attached and one networked.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a USB filter for the local printer (providing, of course the printer is attached via USB and not parallel). I am not sure how to add a printer in Ubuntu (also bear in mind if you get stuck the [VirtualBox Forums](http://forums.virtualbox.org/) are a good resouce base).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This option has the benefit of not removing the printer from the Windows host to connect it to the Guest OS.  Share the printer via [Windows File & Printer Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Share-a-printer).  Then on the guest OS the printer will appear as a Networked printer.

Answer (score 0):

Option won't work.  I am running version 4.02 and the guest reports no USB  devices.  Even though the keyboard , Mouse and speakers are all USB.

Had to resort to option 2 and use a bridged network.

Eric